# parallax responsive website

Tags: web, responsive-design, parallax

i'm making a prallax website, and it has to be also responsive.
here is my site: http://torm.vot.pl/paralaksa/

Any ideas how to make it responsive?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You should look into adding bootstrap to your site. It's an easy and quick way to make sites responsive. You will have to add the appropriate classes to your div tags but it's pretty self explanatory and the website provides examples in order to get the grid system the way you want it.

I inspected your code and you used fixed hardcoded widths (e.g. width: 435px;). You will need to change your widths to be % in order to convert it to responsive design.

http://getbootstrap.com/

Here is an alternative if you decide you don't want to use bootstrap.
https:// developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive?hl=en

Basically in order to achieve a responsive site you need to have a flexible grid using % and utilize media queries to target specific viewport widths.

Media queries: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Also, be sure to include in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope this helps and is a good starting ground for you.